# Exclude system entries with "ls" or "find"

Tags: cygwin, ls, dir, file-attributes, system-file

Compare Cygwin:

```
$ ls -1 -N /cygdrive/c
$Recycle.Bin
cygwin64
Documents and Settings
pagefile.sys
PerfLogs
Program Files
Program Files (x86)
ProgramData
Recovery
System Volume Information
Users
Windows
```

With Command Prompt:

```
> dir /A:-S C:
2018-12-08  10:14 AM    <DIR>          cygwin64
2009-07-13  09:20 PM    <DIR>          PerfLogs
2018-12-15  06:05 PM    <DIR>          Program Files
2018-12-15  05:21 PM    <DIR>          Program Files (x86)
2018-10-31  06:07 PM    <DIR>          ProgramData
2018-11-18  01:10 AM    <DIR>          Users
2018-11-09  08:18 AM    <DIR>          Windows
```

as can be seen, Command Prompt has a way to exclude system items. Does Cygwin
have some way to do this, perhaps with `ls` or `find`?

Comment: As replied by Corinna on the cygwin mailing list https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2018-12/msg00164.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, I am using the `fd` tool:

```
C:\> fd -d 1
PerfLogs
Program Files
Program Files (x86)
Users
Windows
cygwin64
```

https://github.com/sharkdp/fd

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `ls` cygwin already has [`lsattr`](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/lsattr.html) for this purpose

> lsattr — List file attributes
>
> ### Description
>
> The `lsattr` program allows to list file attributes, namely DOS attributes, file sparseness, FS level encryption and compression state, as well as directories' case sensitivity setting.

```
$ lsattr /cygdrive/c
-hs--------- /cygdrive/c/$Recycle.Bin
------------ /cygdrive/c/cygwin64
lsattr: Device or resource busy while trying to open /cygdrive/c/pagefile.sys
------------ /cygdrive/c/PerfLogs
r----------- /cygdrive/c/Program Files
r----------- /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)
-h-------n-- /cygdrive/c/ProgramData
------------ /cygdrive/c/Python27
-hs------n-- /cygdrive/c/Recovery
-hs--------- /cygdrive/c/System Volume Information
r----------- /cygdrive/c/Users
------------ /cygdrive/c/Windows
```

If you need to do somethings on files with or without specific attributes then just **use the first field to filter**. For example to operate on items with system attribute:

```
$ for d in $(2>/dev/null lsattr /cygdrive/c | grep -P '^..s' | cut -d' ' -f2); \
do echo "$d"; done
/cygdrive/c/$Recycle.Bin
/cygdrive/c/Recovery
/cygdrive/c/System
```

You can also use `--long` to get the long attributes

```
$ lsattr --long /cygdrive/c
/cygdrive/c/$Recycle.Bin     Hidden, System
/cygdrive/c/cygwin64         ---
lsattr: Device or resource busy while trying to open /cygdrive/c/pagefile.sys
/cygdrive/c/PerfLogs         ---
/cygdrive/c/Program Files    Readonly
/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86) Readonly
/cygdrive/c/ProgramData      Hidden, Notindexed
/cygdrive/c/Python27         ---
/cygdrive/c/Recovery         Hidden, System, Notindexed
/cygdrive/c/System Volume Information Hidden, System
/cygdrive/c/Users            Readonly
/cygdrive/c/Windows          ---
```

---

Note that Linux itself also has a [similarly named program](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lsattr.1.html), but for listing files along with their [extended attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes)

```
/snap$ lsattr
--------------e----- ./core20
--------------e----- ./README
--------------e----- ./docker
--------------e----- ./bin
--------------e----- ./auto-cpufreq
--------------e----- ./lxd
--------------e----- ./ccls
--------------e----- ./snapd
--------------e----- ./core
--------------e----- ./core18
/snap$ ll
total 48
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096 Mar  7 21:53 ./
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root 4096 Mar 16 15:55 ../
-r--r--r--  1 root root  548 Feb  2 00:29 README
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Mar 15 03:46 auto-cpufreq/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Mar 17 20:53 bin/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Feb 23 09:19 ccls/
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Mar 23 11:36 core/
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Feb 23 05:19 core18/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Mar  7 21:52 core20/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Feb 22 18:57 docker/
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Mar 17 20:53 lxd/
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Mar 24 04:17 snapd/
```